# How can I search for a phrase Like O'% in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql database that contains people's names. Of course there are names stored that begin with `O'`.

If I try to retrieve the name "O'Brien" with sql like this:-

```
SELECT person_sname
FROM people
WHERE person_sname = 'O\\\'Brien'
```

Then I get the expected result. However, if I try to retrieve all names beginning with "O'" like this:-

```
SELECT person_sname
FROM people
WHERE person_sname like 'O\\\'Brien'
```

Then I get an empty result set. My goal is to search for `like "O\\\'"`.

Is there any explanation of why this is happening? I have searched the MySql manual and can find no explanation of why my search shouldn't work as expected.

Other questions I have found deal with storing the escaped string or with retrieving it using `=` which works faultlessly, I specifically want to use the `like` clause on this occassion.

To clarify: I have tried the following also:-

```
SELECT person_sname
FROM people
WHERE person_sname like 'O\'Brien' escape "\'"

SELECT person_sname
FROM people
WHERE person_sname like 'O\'Brien'

SELECT person_sname
FROM people
WHERE person_sname LIKE 'O\'Brien'
ESCAPE '~'
```

The string is escaped on insertion to the db usimg `mysql_real_escape_string()` and is stored as `O\'Brien` (for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` is the default `ESCAPE` character for [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) so you need to either escape it again or define a different `ESCAPE` character.

I wouldn't store names with escape characters like that anyway.

```
SELECT 
        CASE WHEN name LIKE 'O\\\'Brien' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,             /*0*/
        CASE WHEN name LIKE 'O\\\\\'Brien' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,           /*1*/        
        CASE WHEN name LIKE 'O\\\'Brien' ESCAPE '~' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,  /*1*/
        CASE WHEN name = 'O\\\'Brien' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END                 /*1*/
FROM
(SELECT 'O\\\'Brien' as name) T
```

Comment: Yes, your query gives me those results, but I don't understand how it helps me. Sorry for being dense.

Comment: @vascowhite - Any of those last 3 conditions in the `WHERE` clause should match. Note they are not the same as what you already tried. The number of slashes is different.

Comment: `I wouldn't store names with escape characters like that anyway`. How should I store a `'` then? I'm at a stage where changing this is no problem.

Comment: @vascowhite - I'd just store it as `O'Brien`. The `\\` obviously isn't part of the actual surname/data.

Comment: @vascowhite - I don't work with PHP/MySQL myself but am sure it must be possible to insert names like `O'Brien` without having to insert escape characters? Might be worth another question.

Comment: I took your advice and changed the schema to store the names as is. It all works perfectly now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You were injecting a literal backslash. This is enough:

```
SELECT person_sname
FROM people
WHERE person_sname = 'O\'Brien'
```

To test:

```
SELECT 'O\\\'Brien', 'O\'Brien'
```

**Update:** There's already an accepted answer so I'll just add a couple of clarifications.

First, I had overlooked the fact that stored data was corrupted. Needless to say, that explains why `person_sname = 'O\\\'Brien'` is true.

Second, the `\` character has two usages in MySQL syntax:

1. It's the character used to compose [escape sequences](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences): `\n`, `\t`...
2. It's the default escape char to insert literal `%` and `_` characters in [LIKE expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like): `foo LIKE '%abc\%def%'`

The problem is that inserting a `\` symbol in a LIKE expression triggers both behaviours so you actually need to insert *four* backslashes to get *one*:

```
person_sname like 'O\\\\\'Brien'
```

... unless you change the second meaning with the `ESCAPE` clause:

```
person_sname like 'O\\\'Brien' escape '|'
```

Of course, if data was not corrupted you could simply:

```
person_sname = 'O\'Brien'
person_sname like 'O\'Brien'
```

Comment: +1 Still doesn't explain why it (apparently) works for `=` though.

Comment: Thanks for the update, that explains a lot. I've refactored my schema to hold the data "un-corrupted" and that has allowed my original query to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty standard in most SQL dialects:

```
SELECT person_sname
FROM people
WHERE person_sname like 'O''Brien' -- same as = 'O''Brien'

SELECT person_sname
FROM people
WHERE person_sname like 'O''Brien%' -- O'Brien plus more stuff

SELECT person_sname
FROM people
WHERE person_sname like 'O''%' -- O'plus more stuff
```

Note that you cannot use " for strings if [ANSI_QUOTES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) are on, since "" are for identifiers.

Comment: The OP is storing the `\\` in the name for some reason so they still will have issues with that character.

Comment: @MartinSmith That's unfortunate and not really clear from the question.

Comment: Well that is assuming that I was interpreting the last line (added as an edit) correctly...

Answer (score 0):

`like "O'%"` should be sufficient. You don't need any backslashes here.