# How can i check name with single quotes in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have used below code for checking *lastname(case sensitive)* from DB.

```
SELECT * FROM BL12_anncurtis_existing_customers WHERE BINARY LastName LIKE 'ravi'
```

Its work fine. But, it does not work when the name like below, I passes this last name using *php variable($lname)*.

```
SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE BINARY LastName LIKE '$last_name'
SELECT * FROM BL12_anncurtis_existing_customers WHERE BINARY LastName LIKE 'O'Connor'
```

How can I resolve this?.

Comment: You simply need to escape the single quote.

Comment: I had a similar question. The answers to that may be of use to you. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8807690/212940

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're building the query in your PHP script, use the [addslashes](http://www.php.net/addslashes/) function on the value you are searching for:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM BL12_anncurtis_existing_customers WHERE BINARY LastName LIKE '" . addslashes($name) . "'"
```

This will escape any characters that need it and will produce the result you are looking for.

Another solution is to use double quotes in the query instead of single quote:

```
SELECT * FROM BL12_anncurtis_existing_customers WHERE BINARY LastName LIKE "O'Connor"
```

but I think I prefer the first solution

Comment: i passes this last name using php variable($lname).

    SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE BINARY LastName LIKE '$last_name'

Comment: @Ravichandran: You can also use addslashes when passing the variable in the first place, ie addslashes($lname)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape all single quotes with a single quote:

```
SELECT * FROM BL12_anncurtis_existing_customers WHERE BINARY LastName LIKE 'O''Connor'
```

Answer (score 2):

this should work.

```
SELECT * FROM BL12_anncurtis_existing_customers WHERE BINARY LastName LIKE 'O\'Connor'
```

and for php of course, you have mysql_escape or all PDO prepared statements that will take care of this automatically , given the LIKE value you use is bound to a php variable.

Comment: i passes this last name using php variable($lname). SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE BINARY LastName LIKE '$last_name'

Comment: never do that !!! its SQL injection paradise !!! each PHP variable used in your PHP SQL string should at least be passed through mysql_real_escape_string or if you use PDO, use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

you can write yourself a little program which uses regex for matching quotes, the program can validate and fix mistakes made by user.

Answer (score 0):

You should be escaping your string  with `mysql_real_escape_string()`

if you have magic_quotes_gpc turned on (which you should know is a bad idea). This means that strings gathered from $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIES are escaped for you (i.e., "O'Connor" -> "O\'Connor").

Once you store the data, and subsequently retrieve it again, the string you get back from the database will not be automatically escaped for you. You'll get back "O'Connor". So, you will need to pass it through mysql_real_escape_string()

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM sometable where LastName LIKE '%''%'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
WHERE BINARY LastName LIKE "O'Connor"
```

this works for me

I think that the `\'` may be better, but both work